# Php search filter showing all rows without filtering

Tags: php, mysql

While displaying the filtered data, this sql can filter data as per $locationone and $locationtwo.

But it is failing to filter data as per **$cate**

I mean its displaying all the rows from both locations and failing to filter it as per **science(topic)**

```
$cat= "science";
$cate= preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $cat);
$locationone= "dhk";
$locationtwo= "ctg";
preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $locationone);
preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $locationtwo);
$sql= "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN user ON post.user_id= user.id
WHERE post.topic LIKE '%$cate%'
AND post.location LIKE '%$locationone%' 
OR post.location LIKE '%$locationtwo%'
order by post_id desc";
```

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and use prepared statements. Also run your query in phpmyadmin or workbench, to test them

Answer (score 0):

Logical operator `OR` has lower prescedence than `AND`. So you need to surround the `OR`ed conditions with parentheses:

```
WHERE 
    post.topic LIKE '%$cate%'
    AND (post.location LIKE '%$locationone%' OR post.location LIKE '%$locationtwo%')
```

Without the parentheses, your code is equivalent to:

```
WHERE 
    (post.topic LIKE '%$cate%' AND post.location LIKE '%$locationone%')
    OR post.location LIKE '%$locationtwo%'
```

Here you can see that this code will allow locations that match on `'locationtwo'` whatever the value of `topic`.

Important note: you do want to use prepared statements and parameterized queries everywhere in your code, for security and efficiency. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for how to proceed.